# How to show row in view mode if action button is pressed in jqgrid if single click starts edit

Tags: jqgrid

jqGrid inline edit starts on single in click by onSelectRow event below.
Save and cancel action buttons are turned on.

Save or cancel button click does not end inline edit. Row remains in edit mode after clicking to those buttons.
It looks like button click causes onSelectRow event which re-starts inline edit.

How to end single click inline edit in clicked in save or cancel action button ?

```
$(function () {
    var grid = $("#grid");
    grid.jqGrid({
          colModel: [{"name":"_actions","width":45,"formatter":"actions",
          "formatoptions":{"keys":true,"delbutton":false,"afterSave":function (rowID, response) {
                  cancelEditing($('#grid'));
                  aftersavefunc(rowID, response);
            }
,"onError":errorfunc
,"onEdit":function (rowID) {
       if (typeof (lastSelectedRow) !== 'undefined' && rowID !== lastSelectedRow)
                       cancelEditing($('#grid'));
                       lastSelectedRow = rowID;
       }
}},
...
},

       onSelectRow: function (rowID) {
        lastSelectedRow = rowID;
    $("tr#" + lastSelectedRow + " div.ui-inline-edit, " + "tr#" + lastSelectedRow + " div.ui-inline-del").hide();
    $("tr#" + lastSelectedRow + " div.ui-inline-save, " + "tr#" + lastSelectedRow + " div.ui-inline-cancel").show();
    $("#grid").jqGrid('editRow', lastSelectedRow );
  }
}


function cancelEditing(myGrid) {
    if (typeof lastSelectedRow !== "undefined") {
        myGrid.jqGrid('restoreRow', lastSelectedRow);
  var lrid = lastSelectedRow;
  $("tr#" + lrid + " div.ui-inline-edit").show();
  $("tr#" + lrid + " div.ui-inline-save, " + "tr#" + lrid + " div.ui-inline-cancel").hide();
    }
}
}
```

**update**

Grid contains checkbox in toolbar which toggles single click edit mode for rapid data entry (autoedit):

```
            onSelectRow: function (rowID) {
              if (!autoedit) {
                if (typeof (lastSelectedRow) !== "undefined" && lastSelectedRow !== rowID)
                  cancelEditing ($(this));
                  return;
                  }
                  beginInlineRowEdit(rowID);
             },
```

Even in this mode text can be selected and copied to clipboard. The issue is that in single click mode click in save and cancel button does not terminate inline edit, maybe this click in interpreted as start edit command. How to check in onSelectRow if clicked in action column and not to start inline edit in this case, making action column not to start inline edit or other idea ?

**update2**

I tried

```
           beforeSelectRow: function (rowID,e) {
            alert( $(e.target).html());
```

}

If clicked in edit button message box is empty. It is empty also if clicked outside check box checkmark column. If clicked outside edit button it contains whole grid html.
How to dedect click in action column ?

**Update 3**

As Oleg suggested I tried

```
beforeSelectRow: function (rowID,e) { 
   if (!jqgrid_beforeSelectRow( rowID, e)) return false;
   beginInlineEdit(rowID, aftersavefunc );
   return true;
              }


function beginInlineEdit(rowID, afterSave) {
    var grid2 = $("#grid");
    if (rowID && rowID !== lastSelectedRow) {
        var scrollPosition = $("#grid").closest(".ui-jqgrid-bdiv").scrollLeft();
        cancelEditing($("#grid"));
        lastSelectedRow = rowID;
        setTimeout(function () {
            grid2.closest(".ui-jqgrid-bdiv").scrollLeft(scrollPosition);
        }, 100);
    }
    $("tr#" + lastSelectedRow + " div.ui-inline-edit, " + "tr#" + lastSelectedRow + " div.ui-inline-del").hide();
    $("tr#" + lastSelectedRow + " div.ui-inline-save, " + "tr#" + lastSelectedRow + " div.ui-inline-cancel").show();

    $("#grid").jqGrid('editRow', lastSelectedRow, true, null, null, null,
                 { _dokdata: FormData },
                 afterSave,
                 errorfunc,
                 function () {  // afterrestorefunc
                     cancelEditing($("#grid"));
                     setFocusToGrid();
                 }
             );
}

jqgrid_beforeSelectRow = function (rowID, e) {
    if ($(e.target).hasClass('ui-icon-cancel')) { return false; }
    if ($(e.target).hasClass('ui-icon-disk')) { return false; }
    if (typeof (lastSelectedRow) !== "undefined" && lastSelectedRow !== rowID)
      cancelEditing($("#grid"));
    return true;
}

function cancelEditing(myGrid) {
    if (typeof lastSelectedRow !== "undefined") {
        myGrid.jqGrid('restoreRow', lastSelectedRow);
        restoreActionsIcons();
    }
}
```

Using regular double-click to start edit. In product grid first row edit button starts edi only first time. after save button is pressed, remaining clicks in edit button are ignored, inline editing does not start. This happends only if first rows in product table. In bottom rows edit can started multiple times. how to fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correct the user have to press Esc after row selection or click the "Cancel" action button if the user not want to edit the line.

I used to use grids which will be used not only for editing, but more for viewing. So I prefer personally to use [ondblClickRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aevents#list_of_events) instead of [onSelectRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aevents#list_of_events) to enter in the inline editing mode. In the case the user can select or just click in the row or make copy to the clipboard some data from the grid. If the user need to edit the row the user can use either double-click of the action buttons.

Comment: Thank you. I updated question. I'm experimenting with single click edit mode to see is it reasonable. It increases data entry speed by saving huge number of mouse clicks.

Comment: @Andrus: I am not quite understand the effects which you described, but I suppose you need to implement some checking inside of `beforeSelectRow` event handler which has `e` as the second parameter. `e.target` is the cell (`<td>`) or it's child element which are clicked. You can return `false` if you want prevent row selection. By the way you can move the code which you have currently in `onSelectRow` into `beforeSelectRow`. In the case you will have the additional information (`e.target`) which you can use.

Comment: @Andrus: I don't know what you do wrong. Look at [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithInlineEditingAndHide1.htm) for example. It displays the `alert( $(e.target).html());` without any problem.

Comment: @Andrus: You can do about the following `if ($(e.target).hasClass('ui-icon-cancel')) { return false;}` to prevent selection of the row if "Cancel" action button clicked.

Comment: thank you very much. I added this but in first row in product table edit button clicks after first clikc are ignored, they will not start inline edit anymore. I updated question.

Comment: In your demo, if clicked inside rectangle in checked column, empty message box appears in IE9.

Comment: @Andrus: If I click on the inside the cell having checkbox I see the message with the text `<input disabled="disabled" value="false" type="checkbox" offval="no">`. I use IE9 too and have the same results on different computers. Additionally I don't sure that I understand correct what you mean under "in first row in product table edit button clicks after first clikc are ignored". Could you explain the problem in other words? I suppose that you should debug your code to find the reason *why* the first click will be ignored.

Comment: Second click in edit button is simply igonered. I havent found the reason why click in first row is ignored. I can create testcase for you. You can see empty messagebox if you click *inside checkbox rectangle inside cell** . FireFox ignores click in this case. If you click inside cell but outside checkbox rectangle you get the result which you posted. This is probably not realated to question, just a simple note.

Comment: @Andrus: In my tests clicking on **disabled** control like disabled checkbox do nothing. Some browsers (IE) do forward double-click on disabled elements. Only clicking **outside** of disabled element, but inside of the cell will definitively fire the click event. You original problem was the *clicking on the action button*. Why you examine clicking of disabled elements?

Comment: Thank you. Moving onSelectRow code to beforeSelectRow and using `if ($(e.target).hasClass('ui-icon-cancel')) { return false;} ` answers the question. I marked it as answer and voted up. User expect that clicking in disabled checkbox start inline edit like clicking in other columns but this is another issue. In non-IE browsers maybe this can solved by blocking checkbox click in other ways or  placing invisible element over checkbox which receives click. In IE maybe forwarded double click in disabled checkbox can catched someway to used to start edit.

Comment: @Andrus: If you really need to have the behavior, that clicking of disabled checkbox should start inline edit you should **not use disabled checkbox** in the case. Instead of that you can save the image of the checkbox and use custom formatter to display pseudo checkbox. Probably there are some other trick how to say browser to call `click` event handler on disabled control, but I don't know it.

Comment: thank you. currently checkbox click looks like minor issue, I'll try to solve more important issues first